# Wrong behavior : dict with the same key based on tuple

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, pandas

Can you explain the behavior of the following :

```python
rows = pd.DataFrame([
    (0, np.nan, np.nan, 'toto'),
    (1, np.nan, np.nan, 'tata')
])

dico = {}

for row in rows.itertuples():
    k = (row[2], row[3])
    v = row[4]
    print('hash(k) : {0}'.format(hash(k)))
    v_prev = dico.setdefault(k, None)
    if v_prev is None:
        dico[k] = v

print('dico : {0}'.format(dico))
```

Result :

```
hash(k) : 3713080549408328131
hash(k) : 3713080549408328131
dico : {(nan, nan): 'toto', (nan, nan): 'tata'}
```

I manage to create a dict with the same key `(np.nan, np.nan)`. I have got this behavior only with `np.nan`. With `None` or whatever else, I get the usual result with only one key.

Answer (score 1):

What might help is that `np.nan == np.nan` is false.

Hence what is happening is that your dictionary should hash your key, then realizes it falls on an existing key and finally compares it with the previous key. As it is not equal - because `nan` is not equal to `nan` - it should store it in another place to avoid a collision.

But I cannot explain why

```
d = {}
d[(np.nan, np.nan)] = 3
d[(np.nan, np.nan)] = 5
print(d)
```

renders `{(nan, nan): 5}`

Comment: It's because:  `(np.nan, np.nan) == (np.nan, np.nan)` is `True`. This is a result of tuple comparison uses `is` to check for equality and then falls back on `__eq__` if the `is` check fails (probably as an optimization).  See [`PyObject_RichCompareBool`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/c-api/object.html#PyObject_RichCompareBool) which is heavily used in [`tuplerichcompare`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/tupleobject.c#l568)

Comment: I don't see where `is` operator is used in  the C code and explains  `(np.nan,) == (np.nan,) == True`. In my opinion, each element must compare equal but `is` operator  is not involved

Answer (score 0):

It's due to DataFrame casting into `numpy.float64`.
The behavior of `np.float64('nan')` is different from `np.nan` or `None`.
So `np.float64('nan') is np.float64('nan')` is `False` whereas `np.nan is np.nan` is `True` because it is one unique nan stored in numpy module.

So to avoid collision, dict checks if the keys are the same and use `is` opérator